# promise server error when creating new meteor project

Tags: meteor

I'm getting the following error when I try and create a new meteor project:

```
C:\Users\joshm\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:190
  throw error;
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

this is a new problem and as a bit of backstory of how I got to this point:

1) yesterday my project was working perfectly, however I realised that not all of my packages were up to date. It appeared if some had dependancies on others and so couldn't update any further, I removed most of them to see if I could update the specific one I wanted to update

2) now with many of the packages uninstalled I tried to update and I got the same error as I'm getting above. When trying to run the project I also get the same error. I put the packages back in where they were before in hopes that it will fix the problem

3) adding the packages back in doesn't fix the problem and I still get the same error when trying to run the project. I copied all of my document files into a new folder and tried to make a new project to get a clean start

4) when trying to create the new project I get the same error. However it appears as if all of the standard Meteor files are created - the clicking counter. I attempt to run the new clicking counter and once again get the same error, and I also got a firewall alert which I've never had before when trying to run a meteor project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try deleting .meteor from your home directory, and re-install meteor.

Comment: thanks, reinstalling meteor solves the problem, I was just hoping it wouldn't have to come to that

Comment: I had the same problem recently, and it took me ages to work it out (in fact a fellow SO dude suggested it), It was breaking when I upgraded to 1.4.2, but still ok with earlier versions. In a way it's good to know that you can simply start again without risking Armageddon :)

Comment: I mean, there's a little armageddon but it's to be expected haha

Comment: Yep, what doesn't kill you makes you stronger. Then you are more likely to remember it for next time!

Answer (score 1):

for me deleting local meteor installtion on C:\Users\joshm\AppData\Local.meteor\ wasn't enough.

I also had to delete 
**.meteor/local** folder inside **my project folder**