# Cannot set property fullcalendar of undefined in Meteor React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, npm, fullcalendar

I am trying to use fullcalendar-reactwrapper npm package in my meteor react application. But, I am getting the error when using import:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
import FullCalendar from 'fullcalendar-reactwrapper';
```

This is the error I am getting,

C:\Users\aruns\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\promise\0.11.1\npm\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:218
      throw error;

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'fullCalendar' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\PRJ\ldrre\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:26051:19)
at $.fullCalendar.version (C:\PRJ\ldrre\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:26028:37)
at Object.map../af (C:\PRJ\ldrre\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:26037:3)
at __webpack_require__ (C:\PRJ\ldrre\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:30:30)
at Object.defineProperty.value (C:\PRJ\ldrre\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:25910:21)
at __webpack_require__ (C:\PRJ\ldrre\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:30:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\PRJ\ldrre\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:41903:18)
at __webpack_require__ (C:\PRJ\ldrre\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:30:30)
at C:\PRJ\ldrre\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:76:18
at C:\PRJ\ldrre\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:79:10
at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (C:\PRJ\ldrre\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:3:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\PRJ\ldrre\node_modules\fullcalendar-reactwrapper\lib\index.js:10:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at npmRequire (C:\PRJ\ldrre\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\npm-require.js:133:10)
at Module.useNode (packages\modules-runtime.js:664:18)
at index.js (packages\modules.js:952:8)
```

I am using Meteor 1.8, and the below is my npm diff after fullcalendar,

```
C:\PRJ\ldrre>git diff package.json
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index 52bca3d..4628971 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -16,6 +16,7 @@
     "commonmark": "^0.28.1",
     "core-js": "^2.5.5",
     "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
+    "fullcalendar-reactwrapper": "^1.0.7",
     "griddle-react": "^1.13.1",
     "handlebars": "^4.0.11",
     "jquery": "2.2.4",

C:\PRJ\ldrre>git diff package.json
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index 52bca3d..4628971 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -16,6 +16,7 @@
     "commonmark": "^0.28.1",
     "core-js": "^2.5.5",
     "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
+    "fullcalendar-reactwrapper": "^1.0.7",
     "griddle-react": "^1.13.1",
     "handlebars": "^4.0.11",
     "jquery": "2.2.4",
```

Please let me know what I am missing here. Thanks in advance for your help :-)

Comment: Many forum suggested to remove .meteor local, I have even tried project from new folder, no luck. I am using windows 10. Now trying the ultimate solution of uninstall meteor and installing it again.

Comment: Are you using the component anywhere in your code? It seems like a runtime error for a misconfigured component rather than a compilation error due to failure to import a module. If so, please include the code where you are using the component, and try to see if without using it you are still getting the same error. Also, are you trying to do a SSR?

Comment: No luck. Getting the same error even after re-installing meteor.

Comment: No I am not using the component anywhere, due to the error I removed the code, and trying only with import. SSR - No the module where this is imported is only on client side

Comment: The [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fullcalendar-reactwrapper) appears to depend on the following packages: `fullcalendar, jquery, moment, react, react-dom`. It's not clear if you have installed all of those packages into your application as well? The error message suggests that maybe the first one in particular is missing.

Comment: I do have the packages. The issue is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634403/promise-server-error-when-creating-new-meteor-project, But the solutions are not working for me